# Is the peak value received power at carrier frequency in the power spectrum

Tags: signal-processing, spectrum-analyzer

Is the peak value of spectrum at carrier frequency received power? I am transmitting the signal with 12 dBm power at 4Ghz carrier frequency. The signal is modulated with 4GHz carrier frequency with BPSK modulation scheme type. The signal is transmitted to the oscilloscope via coaxial cable. For further processing, the oscilloscope is connected to PC via ethernet cable. So when I measured the output signal in VSA software in that PC, then I saw the peak value at 4GHz carrier frequency -3.57dBm which is lower than expected value as there is no attenuator used between the receiver and transmitter. The output is shown as below:

[image]

So my question: what is the received power at carrier frequency 4GHz? The peak value is shown -3.57dBm at 4 GHz and measured power at the occupied bandwidth is 9.933dBm. So which one is received power at this carrier frequency?

Comment: I can't answer your question but your first sentence is missing some words. An edit is required.

Comment: Since this is a **broadband** signal you **must** measure over the complete bandwidth.  The peak value is in the power in the current **resolution BW setting** of the instrument. For broadband signals the **integrated power** (over frequency) is what matters so 9.9 dBm is the actual power.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!
That means my received power will be 9.9 dBm while transmitting 12dBm power. This totally makes sense now. Is this actual power signal power?

Comment: Did you also mean, if the signal is transmitted through the wireless system, then we should consider the peak value at the carrier frequency for received power?  Am I right?

Comment: No. As a counterexample, Binary offset carrier modulation has (ideally) zero power at the carrier frequency. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYpFx.jpg

Comment: Can you please explain the graph you have attached? Really appreciating your reply